# Spring Boot Auto Config spring.factories

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm following the instructions [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.M8/single/spring-cloud.html#custom-rest-template) to provide a custom RestTemplate.

- I've created the spring.factories file and verified that it is in the
  META-INF directory or the JAR.
- I've created the class as described.
- I've added some log statements in my

  `CustomConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration` and they do not appear after I run the application.

  It seems like the spring.factories file is being ignored.

How can I make the application load my spring.factories file?

Comment: I don't have enough information. What does `spring.factories` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add a configuration:

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

and pls provide your version of spring-cloud nexttime

Comment: The link to the documentation included the version Finchley.M8.  I will make the version explicit next time.