# Library with Spring AutoConfiguration: spring.factories and what else?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We intend to develop a library with Spring Components that all of our Spring Applications should have, like Beans that connect to our monitoring, administration and ochestration services.

The idea was, to make use of Springs' "AutoConfiguration"-mechanism.

For a Starter I wrote a class `com.mycorp.project.basic.startup-notification.StartupNotificationPublisher.class` which, uppon "ApplicationStartedEvent" sends a Message via our favorite message broker (which for the exmample shall be a log file), saying hello to the world.

An instance of this class shall be created through the configuration class `com.mycorp.project.basic.startup-notification.autoconfiguration.StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration.class`

```
package com.mycorp.project.basic.startup-notification
// ... Imports
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StartupNotificationPublisher {
    private final String topic;

    private final Logger messagePublisher = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupNotificationPublisher.class);

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationStartedEvent(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {
        messagePublisher.info("{}: Hello, Attention, I am here!", topic);
    }
}

package com.mycorp.project.basic.startup-notification.autoconfiguration
// ... Imports
@Configuration
public class StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    StartupNotificationPublisher startupNotificationPublisher()
    {
        return new StartupNotificationPublisher("helloTopic");
    }
}
```

Finally, to make the autoconfiguration work, I placed a File `spring.factories` in the `META-INF`-Folder of the jar (*yes, it is there!*), containing:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.mycorp.project.basic.startup-notification.autoconfiguration.StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration
```

I assumed, this will make spring do its magic, find that file when I add the dependency, run the configuration and create that bean to publish the message.

This however is not what happens. Only when I add the package to the scan path of my `@SpringBootApplication`, I will get my message.

*What did I miss? Are there more specific requirements like special project structures? Do I need to have a library called spring-boot-starter or anything like that?*

- [Not a Duplicate of this Question: That one is about Spring Cloud Config which we don't use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49520102/spring-boot-auto-config-spring-factories)
- Not a Duplicate of any of the Questions where spring.factories does not end up in META-INF in the .jar, because in my case it is there.

ProjectStructure:

```
rootDirectory
|-src
|  |-main
|    |-java
|    | |-com/mycorp/project/basic/startup-notification
|    |                            |-autoconfiguration
|    |                            | |-StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration.java
|    |                            |-StartupNotificationPublisher.java
|    |-resources
|      |-META-INF
|        |-spring.factories
|-build.gradle
|-...etc...
```

Resulting Jar Structure:

```
.jar
|-META-INF
| |-spring.factories
|-com
  |-mycorp
    |-project
      |-basic
        |-startup-notification
          |-autoconfiguration
          | |-StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration.class
          |-StartupNotificationPublisher.class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Factories, if configured correctly, have nothing to do with component scanning.

I can confirm that you did everything right, the same configuration worked for my projects many times. So to track what happens:

1. Make sure that given the module "abc", you place the `spring.factories` file in:

`abc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

2. Make sure that the library jar indeed contains this file and it indeed resides in the artifact (your spring boot application). For that open the application with WinRar (or similar tool) and nagivate to `BOOT-INF/lib` - the jar should be there - open the jar and check that `META-INF/spring.factories` folder is there. If something is wrong here, check the dependencies in `pom.xml` the autoconfiguration module should be defined as a dependency of your spring boot application.
3. Make sure that the configuration indeed loads (which means in turn the autoconfig module is recognized):

Rewrite the configuration in the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration {

    public StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration() {
          System.out.println("Loading the configuration StartupNotificationAutoConfiguration"); // or use logging framework
    }

   @ConditionalOnMissingBean
   @Bean
   StartupNotificationPublisher startupNotificationPublisher()
   {
    return new StartupNotificationPublisher("helloTopic");
   }
}
```

If you see this message, then auto-configuration module is there and gets loaded by spring.

4. Try to Remove `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation. If the bean is defined in your application it will take precendence over beans defined in auto-configuration modules anyway. It can be a source of your issue as well.

Comment: I feel so ashamed, it was a problem with the @ConditionalOnMissingBean. In my actual code I had it `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name="StartupNotificationPublisher")` and from an older experiment, a Bean with this name did exist (same class name, diffrent package).  Thanks for your help with debugging.

Comment: Cool, Really glad to hear you've got it sorted. Keep it up and good luck   :)

Answer (score 17):

I spent literally days on a similar issue and this is what worked for me. If you're using Spring boot 3+ they changed all this! You can find the change documented in the 2.7 release notes here: [2.7 release notes#auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#auto-configuration-registration). In release 2.7 they supported both the old and new ways for backwards compatibility and marked spring.factories as deprecated ([deprecation notice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#deprecations-in-spring-boot-27)). They removed support completely in 3.0! You can find the removal information in the 2.7 -> 3.0 migration guide here: [spring boot 2.7 -> 3.0 migration guide#auto-configuration files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#auto-configuration-files). In essence, you're now required to annotate your top level auto-configuration class with `@AutoConfiguration` and add the fully qualified name to a file in this location; `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports`; yes this is the name of the file. The different auto-configuration classes will be separated by newlines instead of a comma-separated string like in `spring.factories`.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for this important info! Yet, it seems, _spring.factories_ still works - until further notice (_"For backwards compatibility, entries in spring.factories will still be honored."_ ~ from your link) - I wonder if it is acceptable to provide both files in parallel to have it compatible with both Spring 2.x and 3.x?

Comment: @derM Your comment made me go and double check the information, turns out I was reading 2.7 release notes instead of 3.0. I've done more digging and edited my answer. The deprecation of spring.factories was for spring boot 2.7 release, in 3.0 they completely removed support for that file.

Comment: I ran into this today, and on spring boot 3.0.6 spring.factories doesn't work any more. I couldn't get my autoconfiguration thing to fire up until I got it moved to the new location. And their documentation still shows the old way of doing it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StartupNotificationPublisher {
private final String topic;

private final Logger messagePublisher = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupNotificationPublisher.class);

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    messagePublisher.info("publisher constructed");
}


@EventListener
public void onApplicationStartedEvent(ApplicationStartedEvent event) {

    messagePublisher.info("{}: Hello, Attention, I am here!", topic);
}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attempt to help. Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. I would have been surprised, That component scan should find only the configuration itself, which triggered the ComponentScan.

Comment: `Finally, to make the autoconfiguration work, I placed a File spring.factories in the META-INF-Folder of the jar (yes, it is there!),`  you are doing this by placing the META-INF-Folder in the resource folder, right ?

Comment: Yes. And I verify it is in the JAR by opening the JAR with my favorite Zip-Program, where I find in the root directory the two children: "META-INF" with the appropriate content and "com" (with the /mycorp/project/...)

Comment: @derM I guess auto-configuration is working but the problem here is the `@EventListener` is not fired(which is a different issue). to prove it can you plz add `@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    messagePublisher.info("publisher constructed");
}`

Comment: @derM if the log `publisher constructed` is printed in the console then auto configuration is working